# Google App Engine Billing Monitor

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, monitoring, billing

I would like to build a simple app monitor for my GAE app that sends me emails when I've hit certain markers (80%, 85%, 90%, 95%, 98% and 100%) of my billing ceiling. Thus, if my billing ceiling for a given day was, say, $50, I would get emails when I reached $40, $42.5, $45, $47.5, $49 and $50 respectively. The purpose of this monitor is (obviously) to alert me that I may need to increase my billing ceiling or prepare for some kind of failover event before my app gets shut down.

Before I go heading down the track of writing my own monitor, I was wondering if GAE comes with this kind of functionality right out of the box. Nothing in their documentation seems too suggest that they do.

If they don't provide such a service, does GAE expose some kind of secured API that I could hit (e.g., `public double getPercentBillingCeiling()`, etc.)? If not, do any GAE gurus have any idea what I could use to automate the collection of this kind of information? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a programmatic service that allows you access to your quotas. However, this sounds like a perfectly reasonable feature request (or set of feature requests). You may wish to star any existing features in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) ([this one](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=655) might fit the bill), or file a new one if your specific requirements aren't met.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Holevoet (+1)! That sounds *exactly* like what I was looking for...so how do we get this prioritized :-)? It seems like there's been demand for this since 2008... whose door needs to be beat down?!? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I suppose I could implement a *makeshift* temp solution with some kind of screen-scraping? Just use `HttpClient` or something to log in to my account, poll the right URL and analyze the quota data sent back in the HTTP response maybe?

Comment: App Engine's billing model changed significantly late last year, so I suspect this has renewed interest in this type of feature. However, I can't comment on prioritization any more than the general rule of "more stars help".

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend the screen scraping approach — it will be brittle and might run afoul of the App Engine terms of use.

Comment: Ahhh, duly noted :-) Thanks again, and for what it's worth from a lone developer, this is definitely a *must* have for any performance-obsessed developer.

Comment: So @Dan Holevoet (and anyone else who's listening)...I posted this question more than 2 years ago... any changes or updates? Just curious!